# Many-To-Many association for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

We have a problem with Many-To-Many association for 3 models in Rails 4. Let see:

Category Many-To-Many Player
Player Many-To-Many Video
Video Many-To-Many Category

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists
  has_many :categories, through: :playlists
  has_many :videos, through: :playlists
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists
  has_many :categories, through: :playlists
  has_many :players, through: :playlists
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists
  has_many :videos, through: :playlists
  has_many :players, through: :playlists
end

class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :category
end
```

When we create new Category with 2 Players and 2 Videos, relations of associated models don't contact with each other.

```
@category = current_user.categories.create(category_params)
```

In table we see:

```
#<Playlist id: 37, video_id: nil, player_id: 1, category_id: 87>, 
#<Playlist id: 38, video_id: nil, player_id: 6, category_id: 87>, 
#<Playlist id: 39, video_id: 154, player_id: nil, category_id: 87>,
#<Playlist id: 40, video_id: 155, player_id: nil, category_id: 87>
```

But we want cartesian product of Videos and Players:

```
#<Playlist id: 37, video_id: 154, player_id: 1, category_id: 87>, 
#<Playlist id: 38, video_id: 155, player_id: 6, category_id: 87>, 
#<Playlist id: 39, video_id: 154, player_id: 1, category_id: 87>,
#<Playlist id: 40, video_id: 155, player_id: 6, category_id: 87>
```

How should we do that?

Comment: Please post the `category_params` method.

Comment: @Pavan, I hope this will help you to find a solution for our problem.     
`params.require(:category).permit(:name, player_ids: [], videos_attributes: [:content])`

Comment: May be you should permit `video_ids: []`.Try adding it like this `params.require(:category).permit(:name, player_ids: [], video_ids: [],videos_attributes: [:content])`

Comment: @Pavan, Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Video identificators don't come as parameters from form. All models are created, but don't connect with each otherю

Comment: Can you show the log info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to define custom code instead of using default ActiveRecord code.

```
class Category
...
  def self.create_category(user, category_params)
    video_ids = category_params.delete(:video_ids)
    player_ids = category_params.delete(:player_ids)

    create(category_params.merge(:user_id => user.id)).tap do |cat|
      video_ids.each do |video_id|
        player_ids.each do |player_id|
          cat.playlists.create(video_id: video_id, player_id: player_id)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class CategoryController
...
  def create
    Category.create_category(current_user, category_params)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this the most right rails way for problem?

Comment: I think so.  Since your requirements don't follow the default Active Record behavior, you need to write the each loops somewhere.  Writing the code in the Category class keeps the controllers lean.  Subject to debate I think it is more MVC.  The questionable MVC area is that the model is processing the parameters in the form they were passed to the web server, but otherwise MVC is clean.  The contents of the tap could be moved to its own method to be more testable, and would have been in it's own method from TDD.  Again the web params format showing up in a model test is questionable MVC.